# How to start the rails console on Heroku with a multi-buildpack?

Tags: heroku, rails-console, cedar, procfile

I'm deploying to heroku with the [multi-buildpack](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi) on the cedar stack using a custom procfile:

```
web: bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -E $RACK_ENV -c ./config/unicorn.rb
worker: bundle exec sidekiq -e production -C config/sidekiq.yml
console: bundle exec irb -r ./console
```

When I boot my console with `heroku run console` I get `LoadError: cannot load such file -- ./console` and a virgin irb session.

How can I initialize the console with rails and my application environment loaded?

Answer (score 0):

So running `irb` is obviously wrong.
What I needed was `console: bundle exec rails console`